# sqlite ado.net provider - which is the most popular to use? (e.g. phxsoftware, devart, mindscape)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sqlite, ado.net, wrapper

Regarding starting to use SQLite within C# Visual Studio 2008 for a winforms application, it seems from the sqlite site you have to download a sqlite ado.net provider, and there are numerous listed (in .net section of [sqlite wrappers](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers))

**QUESTION - Which is the most popular/robust sqlite wrapper that people are using?**  Some from the list seem to include:

- [phxsoftware](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
- [devart](http://devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/)
- [mindscape](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/)

I'm not sure yet whether I should want or need support for LINQ or EntityFramework.  Most fundamental requirement is just one that allows me to work with a few tables worth of data from the sqlite database within VS2008 easily.

Thanks

Comment: oh - some of these might not be free it seems - I'd really prefer a 'free' option if it were solid

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [phxsoftware](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) alot with C# applications. I works very fast, even with large (ten of thousands) tables. It is also .NET 2 compliant, if that is an issue.

As to the free issue, this package is free.

Comment: Am - are you using LINQ or EntityFramework, or just sticking to using the System.Data.SQLite classes?  I'm wondering for my simple few tables whether it's worth trying to wrap my head around using LINQ or EntityFramework (if it's possible with the wrapper)

Comment: I`m using the the SQLite classes. They are standard to the C# data classes, and have all the standard DataProvider, Parameter, etc.